# How to process multiple levels of results with a single loop in bash?

Tags: bash, loops, if-statement, nested-loops

I need to create a certain loop which will to some extend describe a network with all its nodes. This loop will be part of something else which is not relevant to the topic. As you know in a network one node is connected to another and so on. I have all these nodes in separate files and I need to process them with a loop. Each loop will produce more results within which i need to perform more loops and the number increases exponentially until breaking point is reach. Now i know how to solve this problem with like 50 nested loop's which look like this:

```
declare loopvarnode=($(some command to get list of nodes))
for a in ${loopvarnode[@]}
        do
        declare check1=($(grep ${a[@]} results.file))
        if [[ "$a" == "breaking point" ]]
        then echo "Match found"; break
        elif [[ ! $check1 -z ]]
        then continue
        fi
        echo ${a[@]} >> results.file
        declare loopvarnode1=($(same thing but now we look for results in what was provided by variable $a))
        for b in ${loopvarnode1[@]}
            do
            declare check2=($(grep ${b[@]} results.file))
            if [[ "$b" == "breaking point" ]]
            then echo "Match found"; break
            elif [[ ! $check1 -z ]]
            then continue
            fi
            echo ${b[@]} >> results.file
            declare loopvarnode2=($(same thing but now we look for results in what was provided by variable $b))
            for c in ${loopvarnode2[@]}
                do 
.....
```

After about 50 of these I suppose i should be fine but maybe there's a way to do this properly with one or two loops.

Comment: Use recursion instead of loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursive function instead of copy-paste the same loop:

```
 //$1 is first list parameter. 
    function do_things {    
      for a in ${$1[@]}
      do
        declare check1=($(grep ${a[@]} results.file))
        if [[ "$a" == "breaking point" ]]
        then echo "Match found"; break
        elif [[ ! $check1 -z ]]
        then continue
        fi
        echo ${a[@]} >> results.file
        declare loopvarnode1=($(same thing but now we look for results in what was provided by variable $a))
        do_things loopvarnode1
      done

}
```

Something like that.

Comment: Yes this is the same thing but with less rows however it doesnt really solve the infinite nature of the problem.
Indeed I could have a need to use this function up to 5 times so I will create 5 calls for this function but i might as well have a need for 99 times.
I think that due to the nature of my problem (each loop creates more results within which a loop needs to be performed) I will need to write a manual itteration.

Answer (score 1):

Also just to correct your function, passing an array as an argument will not work directly (i get bad substitution). This is how it worked:

```
function do_things {
    array=( "$@" )
  for a in ${array[@]}
  do
    declare check1=($(grep ${a[@]} results.file))
    if [[ "$a" == "breaking point" ]];
    then echo "Match found"; break
    elif [[ ! -z $check1 ]];
    then continue
    fi
    echo ${a[@]}
    x=$(( $x + 1 ))
    declare loopvarnode1=($(some stuff with $a))
    do_things ${loopvarnode1[@]}
  done }
```